# How to use other class methods inside of another class in same file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I've a scenario where i have to use a Class that extends another class which is not a codeigniter class and inside of the method, i need to call another method to perform Database operation.

How can i achieve?

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/OauthPhirehose.php');

class Get extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('tweets_model');

    }

    public function getall()
    {

        $tags = $this->tags_model->get();
        $result = $tags->row();
        $first = $result->first_tag;
        $second = $result->second_tag;
        return array($first, $second);
    }

    public function insert_raw_tweet($raw_tweet, $tweet_id)
    {
        $this->tweets_model->save_raw($raw_tweet, $tweet_id);

    }

}


class Consume extends OauthPhire {


    public function enqueueStatus($status) {
        $tweet_object = @json_decode($status);

        if (!(isset($tweet_object->id_str))) { return;}

        $tweet_id = $tweet_object->id_str;
        $raw_tweet = base64_encode(serialize($tweet_object));
        echo $tweet_object->text . "\r\n";

         // here i need to use top class method to insert data
        //$this->tasks->insert_raw_tweet($tweet_object, $tweet_id);
    }
}

 $get_track = new Get();
$list = $get_track->getall();

    $stream = new Consume(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);
    $stream->setTrack($list);
    $stream->consume();
```

Answer (score 0):

Load it just like you load a normal third party library stored in /library/ folder, use this method :

```
$this->load->library('OauthPhirehose');
```

Hope this works.